# `mysql_list_dbs` and `mysql_tablename` in php7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm migrating code from php 5.x to php 7 and it seems that there is no alternative function for `mysql_tablename` and `mysql_list_dbs`. I'm having trouble replacing it. Below is how I used it before it was deprecated.

```
{
        $qid = mysql_list_dbs($this->_connectionID);
        $arr = array();
        $i = 0;
        $max = mysqli_num_rows($qid);
        while ($i < $max) {
            $db = mysql_tablename($qid,$i);
            if ($db != 'mysql') $arr[] = $db;
            $i += 1;
        }
        return $arr;
    }
```

Comment: Use a query `SHOW DATABASES` and `SHOW TABLES IN <database>`

Comment: More specifically, this: `$qid = mysql_list_dbs($this->_connectionID);` is equivalent to this: `$qid = mysqli_query($this->_connectionID, "SHOW DATABASES");`

Answer (score 1):

**Migration to mysqli (php7)**

Fortunately `myslq_` and `mysqli_` functions are very similar. The only difference is in letter `i` that you should append to your `mysql_` functions. In most cases you will just have to change function name. Here is the list of the incompatible functions between `mysql_` and `mysqli_`:

```
mysql_client_encoding() 
mysql_list_dbs() (use SHOW DATABASES query)
mysql_db_name() 
mysql_list_fields()
mysql_db_query() 
mysql_list_processes() (use SHOWPROCESSLIST query)
mysql_dbname() 
mysql_list_tables() (use SHOWTABLES query)
mysql_field_flags() 
mysql_listdbs() (use SHOW DATABASES query)
mysql_field_len() 
mysql_listfields()
mysql_field_name() 
mysql_listtables() (use SHOWTABLES query)
mysql_field_table() 
mysql_numfields()
mysql_field_type() 
mysql_numrows() (use mysqli_num_rows() instead)
mysql_fieldflags() 
mysql_pconnect() (append p: to thehostname passed to mysqli_connect())
mysql_fieldlen() 
mysql_result()
mysql_fieldname() 
mysql_selectdb() (use mysqli_select_db() instead)
mysql_fieldtable() 
mysql_table_name()
mysql_fieldtype() 
mysql_tablename()
mysql_freeresult() (use mysqli_free_result() instead)
mysql_field_name() 
mysql_listtables() (use SHOWTABLES query)
mysql_field_table() 
mysql_numfields()
mysql_field_type() 
mysql_numrows() (usemysqli_num_rows() instead)
mysql_fieldflags() 
mysql_pconnect() (append p: to thehostname passed to mysqli_connect())
mysql_fieldlen() 
mysql_result()
mysql_fieldname() 
mysql_selectdb() (usemysqli_select_db() instead)
mysql_fieldtable() 
mysql_table_name()
mysql_fieldtype() 
mysql_tablename()
mysql_freeresult() (usemysqli_free_result() instead)
mysql_unbuffered_query()
```

Helpful link: http://code-epicenter.com/things-you-should-know-when-upgrading-to-php-7/